# Solving a ordinary differential equation with initial conditions using the Laplace Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Problem:

Use the Laplace form to solve the following initial-value problem.

$$ y'' + 6y' + 8y = 16 $$
with
$$ y(0) = 0 $$
$$ y'(0) = 10 $$
and the independent variable is $t$.

Answer:

\begin{align*}
s^2Y(s) -sy(0) - y'(0) + 6 ( sY(s) - y(0)) + Y(s) &=\dfrac{16}{s} \\
s^2Y(s)  - 10 + 6 ( sY(s) ) + Y(s) &=\dfrac{16}{s} \\
(s^2 + 6s+1)Y(s) &= \dfrac{ 16 }{s} + 10 \\
(s^2 + 6s+1)Y(s) &= \dfrac{ 10s + 16 }{s}  \\
Y(s) &= \dfrac{ 10s + 16 }{s( s^2 + 6s+1 )}
\end{align*}
Using an online inverse Laplace calculator, the answer I get is a mess and wrong. The book's answer is:
$$ y= e^{-2t} - 3e^{-4t} + 2 $$
Where did I go wrong?

I wrote the following line:
$$ s^2Y(s) -sy(0) - y'(0) + 6 ( sY(s) - y(0)) + Y(s)
     =\dfrac{16}{s} $$
but it should have been:
$$ s^2Y(s) -sy(0) - y'(0) + 6 ( sY(s) - y(0)) + 8Y(s) 
    =\dfrac{16}{s} $$
with that change, I was able to solve the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $s^2Y(s) -sy(0) - y'(0) + 6 ( sY(s) - y(0)) + 8 Y(s) = \frac{16}{s}$ ?

Comment: @user408858 I found the mistake after I  posted it.